# Explanation of JAXB error: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, jaxb

We're parsing an XML document using JAXB and get this error:

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.]
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)
```

What exactly does this mean and how can we resolve this??

We are executing the code as:

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Results.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(getSchema());
results = (Results) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
```

---

**Update**

Issue appears to be due to this "funny" character in the XML file: `¿`

Why would this cause such a problem??

**Update 2**

There are two of those weird characters in the file.  They are around the middle of the file.  Note that the file is created based on data in a database and those weird characters somehow got into the database.

**Update 3**

Here is the full XML snippet:

```
<Description><![CDATA[Mt. Belvieu ¿ Texas]]></Description>
```

**Update 4**

Note that there is no `<?xml ...?>`  header.

The HEX for the special character is BF

Comment: It means the input is corrupt.... not much I can say without more information.

Comment: Added some more info.  Does that make any sense??  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the section of the XML file that includes the offending text.

Comment: @Marcus: Can you also post `<?xml ...?>` header and the hex representation of the offending part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you problem is that JAXB treats XML files without `<?xml ...?>` header as UTF-8, when your file uses some other encoding (probably ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252, if `0xBF` character actually intended to mean `¿`).

If you can change the producer of the file, you may add `<?xml ...?>` header with actual encoding specification, or just use UTF-8 to write a file.

If you can't change the producer, you have to use `InputStreamReader` with explicit encoding specification, because (unfortunately) JAXB don't allow to change its default encoding:

```
results = (Results) unmarshaller.unmarshal(
   new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

However, this solution is fragile - it fails on input files with `<?xml ...?>` header with different encoding specification.

Comment: Thanks, will try.  Note that I get the same error when I use Xalan/Java to try and format the XML file using XSLT.  Does Xalan also assume UTF-8?

Comment: That works!  Note that this code only runs on this file which will never have the xml header.  

What is the advantage/diff to this approach vs. using this: `results = (Results) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader(inputFile));`

Comment: @Marcus: `FileReader` uses the system default encoding, when `InputStreamReader` uses the explicitly specified one.

Comment: @axtavt: Thanks...this worked for me too..however, um.unmarshall(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) ..... this can parse the string irrespective of the presence of header (with UTF-8) in xml. Why? Another thing, it was not working earlier with... um.unmarshall(new SAXSource(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())))) ..could u plz explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and is a special byte sequence at the start of a UTF file. They are, frankly, a pain in the arse, and seem particularly common when interacting with .net systems.

Try rephrasing your code to use a `Reader` rather than an `InputStream`:

```
results = (Results) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader(inputFile));
```

A `Reader` is UTF-aware, and might make a better stab at it. More simply, pass the `File` directly to the `Unmarshaller`, and let the `JAXBContext` worry about it:

```
results = (Results) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputFile);
```

Comment: I can try that.  Note that there are two of those characters in the file - see the second update to the post.

Comment: Using the `FileReader` looks good.  Got the same error when I just specified the `File`.  Going to validate all my results but this looks good!

Comment: But so I understand, these just seem like "weird" characters, not a "Byte Order Mark", no?  Why do they cause this trouble?

Comment: @Marcus: Well, the BOM *is* a sequence of weird characters, denending on how you look at them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your XML is encoded with UTF-16 but that encoding is not getting passed to the Unmarshaller. With the Marshaller you can set that using `marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-16");` but because the Unmarshaller is not required to support any properties, I am not sure how to enforce that other than ensuring your XML document has `encoding="UTF-16"` in the initial `<?xml?>` element.

Comment: It can't be UTF-16 - attempt to parse UTF-16-encoded XML file as UTF-8 will fail due to wrong markup. It's probably some single-byte encoding.

Comment: You are correct. I was looking at the different encodings and got mixed up.